# Make jQuery work in WordPress/php

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post

I'm building something like a posts gallery and I want to do the following:

1. have thumbnail for each post
2. when a thumbnail is clicked, I want the new post to be loaded in the `<div>` at the top of the page w/o the posts gallery changing.

I want to pass the id of post on `<div>` click and then run the `query_string` there.

I got my thumbnail onclick function:

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
     myLink=$(this).attr('href');
// get the post id into pID by finding p= and then extracting the next char after = from the link
        var t = myLink.indexOf("p=");
        var l = myLink.length;
        var pID = myLink.substring(t+2,l);
        $("#target").post('/?page_id=9', { postID: pID } );       
        $("#target").load("/?page_id=9");

        return false;
});
```

My problem is: `$.post` doesn't work. I've tried it with the `$.ajax` syntax, too, and it still doesn't work. It seems like the jQuery is aborted midway, as any alerts I put in the post or ajax callback functions are being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `admin-ajax`. Wordpress has a specific model for its ajax calls that takes care of security and other stuff. Check out the codex for [admin-ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

When working with jQuery and Wordpress, jQuery needs to be loaded and coded in a certain way to avoid conflicts. [5 Tips For Using jQuery with WordPress](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/) by Eric Martin provides a good explanation.